# Formula to compare two values in Columns in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I am attempting to compare the numerical value in one column with that in another. Then have another column populated depending on the results. I do not know how to write this due to limited experience with Excel. This is what I am attempting to do:
If B1 < C1 then D1 = C1
If B1 > C1 then D1 = B1

Answer (score 0):

You should put your logic(formula) in the cell you want to give a custom behavior.

As I can see you want to put a dynamic value into column D cells (D1).

So, you should put a formula in cell D1 to behave as you want:

```
=IF(B1<C1,C1,B1)  (sometimes you have to use ; instead of , depending on language)
```

It says:

```
If b1<c1 then put C1 into this cell otherwise B1
```

[image: Excel caption]

=IF( Logic, Case-true, Case-False )

In excel the IF operator receives 3 inputs separated by ; sign:

> 1. The logic condition in the first option
> 2. the result you want to use if condition is true
> 3. the result you want to use if condition is false

To use this formula in all lines of column D, just press the black little square in the right corner bottom of the cell and grab it until the line you want

[image]

Comment: I tried typing it in exactly how you have it typed and it says the formula you typed contains an error.

Comment: I had to type it like this =IF(B1<C1,C1,B1) For it to work. Thank for your help

Comment: Now my question is how do I get this formula to work to compare 2 entire columns of numbers side by side and populate the entire D column with all of the results?

Comment: Just grab the "square point" of the right bottom side of the cell until the line you want as i put in the end of the answer

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Worked like a charm!